# I am having trouble formatting a date using datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I am getting a date from an API that I am trying to pass to my template after formatting using datetime but I keep getting this error:

time data `2021-03-09T05:00:00.000Z` does not match format `%Y-%m-%d, %I:%M:%S;%f`

I know I have to strftime and then strptime but I cant get past that error.

I would like to split it into two variables one for date and one for the time that will show in the users timezone.

```py
    date = game['schedule']['date']
    game_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d, %I:%M:%S;%f')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a slightly wrong time format:

```py
game_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

Or (if you remove the last *Z* character from the date string) you can also use `datetime.fromisoformat`:

```py
game_date = datetime.fromisoformat(date[:-1])
```

And then you can extract date and time this way:

```py
date = game_date.date()
time = game_date.time()
time_with_timezone = game_date.timetz()
```